# Cannot implicitly convert type to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I have some code that I am working on (not a dev, but we deal with the hand that we have been dealt) and I have a small, but frustrating error that is popping up, after I have struggled my way through the rest of the issues. In this code:

```
public class ObservableCollection<ReportData>
{
    public string GetQueryData(string date, string ip, string query)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ReportData> result = new ObservableCollection<ReportData>();

        try
        {
            var data = GetRemoteQueryJournal(ip, date, query);

            if (data != null)
            {
                result = GetReporData(data);
            }
                        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

If the class only gets strings, shouldn't the return BE a string? But I get
[image]

Comment: Your `GetQueryData()` function is expecting to return a string, but the type of `result` is `ObservableCollection<ReportData>` which is waht you're trying to return. Obviously that's a mismatch.

Comment: Either return a `string` in the method body or change the method signature to return `ObservableCollection<ReportData>`

Comment: If that's indeed what you want to return, then change the function definition to this: `public ObservableCollection<ReportData> GetQueryData(string date, string ip, string query)`

Comment: Instead of showing us what you're doing, [tell us what you want to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) because what you're doing makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `C#` (or any programming language) function has a standard definition, which looks like this:

```
return_type FunctionName (parameter1_type parameter1_name, parameter2_type parameter2_name,...)
{
}
```

- Parameters are optional
- Return type can be `void`, in which case you don't need to return anything.
- For all other return types, you need to return a value matching the return type.

So let's take a very simple function, which takes in two `int`s as parameters, adds them up, and return the sum as an `int`. It would look like this:

```
int AddTwoInts(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

The return type is `int`, and the `sum` is also `int` so it works fine.

Say you want to add two `int`s but return the sum as a `string` for whatever the reason. Then your function definition would have to look like this:

```
string AddTwoIntsAndReturnAsString(int a, int b)
{
    // function body
}
```

However, in this case, if you had the same function body as before, the compiler will complain:

```
string AddTwoIntsAndReturnAsString(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

Because `sum` is still and `int` but the function wants you to return a string, which is a conflict and the compiler doesn't like that. So it will complain. You can fix this by matching what you return to actual return type.

```
static string AddTwoIntsAndReturnAsString(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum.ToString();
}
```

Now this will get rid of the error, but doesn't necessarily mean that'll fix all problems. Typically if you add two numbers you want the result to be a numeric type where you can do additional calculations later on. So for a function that adds two numbers it makes more sense to actually return an `int`, not a `string`.

Similarly in your case, your `result` is of type `ObservableCollection<ReportData>`. An `ObservableCollection` is essentially a list. So converting it into a `string` and returning just to get rid of the error doesn't make sense, as the function wants to return the above type in order to get some work done later on.

So it'll make more sense to change your function's return type:

```
public ObservableCollection<ReportData> GetQueryData(string date, string ip, string query)
{
    ObservableCollection<ReportData> result = new ObservableCollection<ReportData>();

    try
    {
        var data = GetRemoteQueryJournal(ip, date, query);

        if (data != null)
        {
            result = GetReporData(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I understand this, and when I implement the solution you proposed, I get "The type or namespace 'ReportData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Now, when I look at this, I need to use     using System.Collections.ObjectModel; and reference WindowsBase, which both are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your return statement

```
        return result.ToString();
```

or maybe you want

```
        return result != null ? "It worked":"It failed";
```

That should make the issue clear.  You say this function returns a string but you are returning a different object type.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, as I said, I'm no dev. Thank you!

Comment: That would get rid of the error but I doubt that will actually fix the problem. If you want to return an `ObservableCollection`, returning it as a string won't be useful.

Comment: @dragos_kai -- it may have fixed it but I doubt it is what you want the function to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the return type from `string` to `ObservableCollection<ReportData>` or `ReportData` (depending on your needs).

If you do this and the class only gets strings as you phrased it, then yes the result *will* be strings. This is how generics works.